# Where is the + in email addresses defined?

Tags: email, email-validation, email-address

I know that email addresses, in the local part (before the @ sign), can include a +. And everything after the + can be used by the email system for filtering and other uses. But the email itself is delivered per the part before the + sign.

Example:

```
larry@foo.com         Delivered to larry mailbox on foo.com
jim@foo.com           Delivered to jim mailbox on foo.com
larry+1@foo.com       Also delivered to larry mailbox on foo.com. The +1 can be
                      used for filtering or something else by the recipient
larry+hi_guys@foo.com Also delivered to larry mailbox on foo.com
```

The above works on GMail, Yahoo and other systems.

**Question: Where exactly is it defined in the RFCs?** I looked but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The + isn't defined in the RFC for mail addressing, [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822). It is an implementation by some MTAs in an effort to filter incoming messages to a single mailbox, but the current RFC doesn't' support exposing mailbox structure/filters to senders.

It does leave the handling of the local portion of the address up to the MTA which is where these extensions have been promoted.

There is a proposed RFC, [RFC 5233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5233), for sub addressing that explains plus addressing in detail.

So there is ongoing work to standardize it, but that hasn't yet happened. I know not all MTAs use + addressing for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a definitive blog or newsgroup post that explains the idea? It seems to have achieved a lot of traction, yes?

Comment: Hey Larry, I edited my answer with the proper RFC citations. Sorry was posting in a rush.

Comment: Thank you. Just what I was looking for. Re posting in a rush--standard SO technique: get your initial answer in there asap to be first. Then flesh it out later. Welcome to SO.